# Twitter Buttons not shown

Tags: twitter

I'm developing a chatbot on Twitter standardv1.1 direct messages, the three call-to-action (CTA) buttons to send URLs to appear on the web but when I open my Twitter account from my mobile is not appear, please I need help, thanks [image]

how the url button to show in mobile .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this on Android? There is currently (October 2022) an issue where the buttons do not show in the most recent versions, but a fix is being worked on.

Comment: Thanks, I much appreciated yes I use android and I have another point Twitter max option 20 but on mobile display 6 only do problem-related?